# Как сделать последний слайд OWL или Slick другой шириной?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js, owl-carousel

подскажите каким образом можно задать что бы последний слайд всегда был больше по ширине, owl или slick использовал, но везде есть только отцетровка, так же отлавливал последний активный слайд и добавлял к нему класс, и на класс увеличивал ширину , но при таком действии сбивается правильная работа слайдера, я так понимаю он теряет общую ширину и теряется правильная позиция слайдов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос, что стоит сделать, использовать два слайдера разных слайдера и синхронизировать их между собой, я делал на slick, поэтому использовал свойство ***asNavFor***, для каждого слайдера, и таким образом они взаимодействуют друг  с другом.
Пример скрипта:

```
    $('.slider1').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider2' /// второй слайдер
    });

   $('.slider2').slick({
   slidesToShow: 2,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   arrows: true,
   asNavFor: '.slider1', /// первый слайдер
   focusOnSelect: true,
   });
```

Надеюсь кому-то поможет в будущем это)